# How to use Magento's API asynchronously without OAuth?

Tags: php, api, magento, rest, oauth

I'm working on integrating a Magento store with an existing desktop Point of Sales software. My idea is that this desktop program would connect through Magento's REST API to gather the product list, inventory changes, etc., and it will also commit new products and other updates through the API endpoint.

The problem arises when I don't want the person in charge of the PoS know the API credentials or don't want to bother prompting for them. The best would be to set them up in a config file.

I thought about loading the API authorize page in the background and automatically post the credentials to the login form. But this looks like a nasty approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't make your point of sale system reliant on live connections into a secondary system (i.e.).  Use local data stores for your POS data listings, and have a separate, non-interactive process responsible for getting changes from Magento into your POS.  Live queries from your POS means everything will get borked if there's no internet connection, or you Magento system is down/not-responding.

Comment: Of course the PoS system has it's own data store and doesn't rely on Magento for that. I just want to avoid synchronizing scripts if I can update Magento any time something changes. This process will also queue requests if the system is down or some error arises. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Hi, did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but some words of experience in this matter...

Magento's API can be slow and the user will wait forever for the task to finish especially if the server is under load. We use another application which uses the Magento's SOAP API which I built using java to handle all updates/downloads between magento and our POS. This way the user is not waiting on slow responses, or stopped by loss of connectivity.

We have adopted your queue approcach, and another reason for having 1 application with a queue is that it handles all updates from all users and Only Allows 1 Task To Execute At Once. You need to do this to avoid database locks. e.g. Two users modify a product and you get a table lock error and the update fails. You can also overload the server by flooding it with lots of single user requests to the server. We still have event driven processing as opposed to synch scripts by having our POS send messages to our local app instructing the app about the task and it simply queues the task for processing. Our application has no user interface what so ever and I run it as a System service on our server, with the user credentials stored in a config file.

Comment: Ok, but how did you this? I have the same problem: the credentials window prompt. How did you skipped this step?